# How can I scrape button text specified in HTML into an observable?

Tags: knockout.js

So I have a random button with a random text that somebody put there right in HTML. When the button is clicked its text should be replaced with 'Loading...' and once loading is finished the original text should be returned. Is there a quick and dirty way to do that without involving custom-bindings?

As an idea: I wish the text of a button was defined in HTML and somehow bound to an observable from there. Something like:

```
 <button data-bind="text: $data.buttonText = ko.observable('Click me sucker!'), click: click"></button>
```

Obviously I don't like this idea of altering my view model at the time of binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare observable variable with defaut value (this value will be displayed by default on the screen)and then just change it with new text, when needed.

```
self.buttonText = ko.observable("Click me");

<button data-bind="text: buttonText, click: click"></button>
```

Comment: How can I do it from HTML?

Comment: Ok. In ko model: self.buttonText(null). In html: <button data-bind="text: buttonText() || 'Click me', click: click"></button>. 
On click set self.buttonTest() to 'Loading..' in the ko model.